# How can I write a JSON-Server fetch call with multiple params?

Tags: json-server

Looking for a way to write a simple JSON-Server fetch with multiple parameters. Currently, I can only get the proper results with one parameter; i.e. - "http://localhost:5002/tasks/companyId=1"

I need something along the lines of - "http://localhost:5002/tasks/companyId=1&&?_expand=user" to return the company's tasks with the user information expanded.

Please and thank you for any assistance.

--update--

I was able to get the results I needed with:

```
http://localhost:5002/tasks/?companyId=1&_expand=user
```

Now, I am using this information to show a selected user in an option box. However, when the option box populates, the selected user also shows in the list of all users. Is there a way to prevent this redundancy? The code for populating the box is as follows:

```
<label htmlFor="assignTo" >Assign To</label>
                <select className="form-control"
                    onChange={this.assignTo}
                    id="assignTo" >
                    <option value={this.props.task.userId}>{this.props.task.user.name} {this.props.task.user.surname}</option>
                    {this.props.employees.map(employee => (
                        <option key={employee.id} id={employee.id} value={employee.id}>
                            {employee.name} {employee.surname}
                        </option>
```

Again, I thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Hi! What language are you using; what have you tried so far? Consider reading this help article on [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @lumio I am working on a React project in Visual Studio. I have tried the fetch call of "http://localhost:5002/tasks/companyId=1&?_expand=user"; also, "http://localhost:5002/tasks/companyId=1&&?_expand=user"; and, "http://localhost:5002/tasks/?_expand=user&&companyId=1", but so far, I'm not able to get the expanded user data from the filtered by company tasks table.

Comment: You need to change things on the backend side to allow an URL like that. The thing you describe is a common "problem" with REST APIs. GraphQL tries to solve such shortcomings but is a whole different concept

Comment: I will look into it. I'm sure this isn't a terribly complex issue, but I'm still in the "I don't know, what I don't know" phase of developing. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

So, I was writing an extraneous option before the .map was run. Did not know that I could write an if or ternary statement in the map. My solution became the following:

```
<select className="form-control"
                    onChange={this.assignTo}
                    id="assignTo" >
                    {/* <option value={this.props.task.userId}>{this.props.task.user.name} {this.props.task.user.surname}</option> */}
                    {this.props.employees.map(employee => {
                        if (employee.id === this.props.task.userId) {
                           return <option key={employee.id} id={employee.id} value={employee.id} selected>
                            {employee.name} {employee.surname}
                        </option>
                        } else {
                           return <option key={employee.id} id={employee.id} value={employee.id} >
                            {employee.name} {employee.surname}
                            </option>
                        }
                    })}
                </select>
```

I hope this helps someone else who may need it. Thanks!